# How to confirm a project is using ERC-721A

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I have found a [github repo](https://github.com/chiru-labs/ERC721A/blob/main/projects.md) which shows the implementation of ERC-721A. However, I wonder how to confirm that the project is using this contract. Any criteria that should be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERC-721A is a more efficient implementation of IERC721. Since all of the bytecode has been uploaded on-chain, you know exactly what goes into a smart contract (at least in bytecode).

If we look at the first project listed, Azuki, you can navigate to its contract on Etherscan. Etherscan has a [useful tool](https://etherscan.io/address/0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544#code) that allows creators to upload the Solidity code that the bytecode compiled from. You can check if [Azuki's ERC721A](https://etherscan.io/address/0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544#code#F4#L1) implementation is the same as the one you listed in the Github repo.

Comment: From the first file `Azuki.sol`, I can see that there is a line of code `import "./ERC721A.sol";` If I import this ERC721A contract, can I say that my project is using the 721A standard? 

Another thing is I saw there are some extra files(eg. `ReentrancyGuard.sol`, `IERC721Receiver.sol`), how do I know which files I need for my project?

Thank you

Comment: As for your first concern, yes, just use that contract to say that it's using 721A. To figure out what files you need for your project, you have to figure out what you want your project to do. Look at OpenZeppelin's docs for more info on what each of those contracts do.